# Promise resolved too late in angularjs jasmine test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following jasmine test written with `ng-describe`, run with `karma`.

(I am using [es6-promise](https://github.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise) polyfill for PhantomJS)

```
var myModule = angular.module('MyModule', []);
myModule.service('MyService', [function() {
  return {
    getItems: function() {
      // this will be spied and mocked
    }
  };
}]);

myModule.controller('MyController', ['$scope', 'MyService',
  function($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.items = [];

    $scope.refreshItems = function() {
      MyService.getItems().then(
        function ok(items) {
          $scope.items = items;
          console.log('OK, items.length = ' + items.length);
        },
        function fail(reason) {
          console.error('FAIL')
        }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    };
  }
]);

ngDescribe({
  name: "MyController test",
  modules: ['MyModule'],
  inject: ['MyService', '$rootScope', '$q'],
  controllers: 'MyController',
  tests: function(deps) {

    function getPromise(val) {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve(val);
      });
    }

    it('updates $scope.items', function() {
      spyOn(deps.MyService, 'getItems').and.returnValue(getPromise([4, 5, 6]));
      deps.MyController.refreshItems();
      deps.$rootScope.$digest();

      expect(deps.MyService.getItems).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(deps.MyController.items.length).toBe(3);
      console.log("END OF TEST");
    });
  }
});
```

The test would fail because the promise is resolved too late:

```
LOG: 'END OF TEST'
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0) MyController test updates $scope.items FAILED
        Expected 0 to be 3.
            at d:/git/myproject/test/controllers/ItmngtControllerTest.js:49
LOG: 'OK, items.length = 3'
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 37 of 37 (1 FAILED) (0.085 secs / 0.26 secs)
```

After too long investigation, I figured it that if I use `$q` instead of `Promise`, it will work fine.

```
    function getPromise(val) {
      var deferred = deps.$q.defer();
      deferred.resolve(val);
      return deferred.promise;
    }
```

I'm wondering however, why is this the case, and can I change something in my test to use `Promise` instead of `$q` to make the test pass?

I've read in various places about `$rootScope.$apply()` but wherever I put it, it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: I don't know what triggers the resolve of shimmed ES6 promises, but I doubt it's the scope digest as it is for angular promises. What's wrong with `and.returnValue($q.when([4, 5, 6]))`?

Comment: Yes, I realized that digest only resolves angular-y promises, I was initially thinking it was capable of magically resolving all promises. Ad `$q.when`, yes I can use that too, I overlooked it. My question is, just out of curiosity, is it possible to force angular to resolve native/shimmed Promises too?

Comment: What do native promises do there? Were they used in specs only or also in the app itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular `$q` testing is synchronous, which is a huge advantage. Once scope `$digest()` was called, the one can expect that all `$q` promise chain handlers were called also.

Promises in general (including ES6 implementation) are asynchronous by design, on the other hand. Once the promise was resolved, its handlers will be called on the next tick. So pleasant Angular testing is not that synchronous anymore:

```
it('updates $scope.items', function (done) {
  ...
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(deps.MyService.getItems).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(deps.MyController.items.length).toBe(3);
    console.log("END OF TEST");
    done();
  });
});
```

`Promise` can be mocked for testing purposes to be synchronous, [`mock-promises`](https://github.com/charleshansen/mock-promises) may be used in this case.

And there is [`jasmine-co`](https://github.com/gradecam/jasmine-co) which is intended to make asynchronous testing in Jasmine easier (and it actually does) with ES6 generators and `co`, I'm not aware how good it performs with `ng-describe`.