# Promises with $q and angular in karma, mocha & chai

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, karma-mocha

So i tried to get the promises to work in my angular app tests, can anyone figure out what im doing wrong here it keeps returning:

```
Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.
```

I don't know if it's $q.

**FYI** i also tried the `it('test', function(done){... done();})`

**Controller**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('controller.editor', [])
        .controller('EditorController', EditorController);

    function EditorController($scope, $q) {
        var vm = this;

        angular.extend(vm, {
            hack: hack
        });

        function hack(bool) {
            return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                if (bool) {
                    resolve(true);
                }

                reject(false);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Test**

```
describe('EditorController', function() {
    var vm, scope, $controller, $rootScope, $injector;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');

        //Inject
        inject(function(_$injector_) {
            $injector = _$injector_;
            $controller = $injector.get('$controller');
            $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');

            // Create new scope object
            scope = $rootScope.$new();

            // Bind the controller
            vm = $controller('EditorController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        });
    });

    describe('#addCustom', function() {
        it('test', function(done) {
            var aHack = vm.hack(true);

            aHack.then(function(bool){
                // Resolve
                expect(bool).to.be.eq(true);
                done();
            }, function() {
                // Reject
                expect(bool).to.be.eq(false);
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please ensure the text describes the current situation accurately. With the snippet you posted, do you really get the message `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded. Ensure the done() callback is being called in this test.`? You don't use `done` anywhere in your snippet set up.

Comment: return a promise should be the same, but i updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing promises in angular, it's a best practice to depend on angular machinery to do its job to resolve promises synchronously instead of asynchronously.

This makes the code easier to read and maintain.

It's also less error prone; doing assertions in `.then()` is an anti-pattern because if the callback is never called, your assertions will never run.

To use the angular way of testing, you should:

1. remove `done`
2. do `$rootScope.$digest()` in the test to resolve promises
3. do your assertions

Applying this to your code would be:

```
describe('#addCustom', function() {
    it('test', function() {
        var __bool = false;
        var aHack = vm.hack(true).then(function(bool) {
            __bool = bool;
        });

        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect(__bool).to.be.eq(true);
    });
});
```

But it's tricky, because `$rootScope.$digest` resolves only `$q` promises, not all promises, particularly not the promises created via `Promise()` constructor from various es5 shims, see this:

[Promise resolved too late in angularjs jasmine test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34228045/promise-resolved-too-late-in-angularjs-jasmine-test)

See also:

http://brianmcd.com/2014/03/27/a-tip-for-angular-unit-tests-with-promises.html

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your Promise is resolved before you setup your 'then' behavior.

Take a look at [these examples](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) that all use a setTimeout.