# how can I test this async function over jasmine

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, jasmine

my function in the service is

```
listo: function () {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          setTimeout(function () {
            deferred.resolve(true);

          }, 2000);

          return deferred.promise;
}
```

in jasmine test I have

```
describe("testeando local storage", function () {

  var bd;

  beforeEach(module('modulo'));

  beforeEach(inject(function (bds) {
    bd = bds;
  }));

  beforeEach(function () {
    expect(bd).toBeDefined();
  });

  var valor;

  it("prueba",function(done){
    bd.listo().then(function(res) {
      valor = res;
      done();
    })
  });

  it("pruebita", function(done) {
    expect(valor).toBe(true);
    done();
  });


});
```

I got the following error:

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) testeando local storage should support async execution of test preparation and expectations FAILED
        Expected undefined to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set delay parameter for that test to be more than 2000 ms:

```
it("prueba",function(done){
  bd.listo().then(function(res) {
    valor = res;
    done();
  })
}, 3000);
```

Also you may try to do it for whole the spec:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 3000;
});
```

Comment: i tried this   beforeEach(function() {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 3000;
  });

  var valor;

  it("prueba",function(done){
    bd.listo().then(function(res) {
      valor = res;
      done();
    })
  }, 3000);

  it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
    expect(valor).toBe(true);
    done();
  });

Comment: @IvanParedes Please edit your question with code snippets; it's annoying to try to read them in comments.

Comment: @IvanParedes If it's AngularJS stuff, there is a recommendation to make the test synchronous via `$rootScope.$digest();` call. Follow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180958/promises-with-q-and-angular-in-karma-mocha-chai) and all related links.